# Unity3d: How to script/code a gameObject such as a cube to teleport you onto another gameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am very new to the game developing industry and I do look at tutorials and stuff to help me but that's besides the point. I use Unity3d version 5 to make games. I am making my very first game that is based on parkour. I need to know how to code/script a gameObject such as a cube to make it so that when you step on it, it teleports you onto another cube? Like in some basic games where maybe there is lava and if you fall into it, it just teleports you back to the start of the level.

Answer (score 4):

You need these:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html

That being said, these are Unity basics. I think it's better to start digging into some tutorials before trying to do anything on your own. Otherwise you end up wasting time trying to figure out such things.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you if you are still wondering how to do it after reading unity documentation:

1) Add a collider to player gameobject (if no collider assigned to it already) and "lava cube" gameobject. Select "is Trigger" on the "lava cube" gameobject collider. Make a new tag and put it on the "lava" gameobject. You can call the tag "lava" or whatever you want

2) In the player script declare a Vector3 variable with coordinates of the point where you want to "teleport" the player to.

3) In the same script you have to use OnTriggerEnter(Collider) to detect collisions with gameobjects with tag="lava" and if you detect such a collison you should set the player.transform.position to the vector3 declared before;

```
public Vector3 teleportTo;

void Awake()
{
    teleportTo = transform.position;
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "lava")
    {
        transform.position = teleportTo;
    }
}
```

If you just want to restart the level you can make it even easier:

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "lava")
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
    }
}
```

This is one of the ways you can do it. It is very important that rigidbody, colliders, tags are assigned and configured properly